# Android - Сигнатуры приложений не совпадают

Tags: android, key, signature

Я экспортировал приложение в .apk файл, установил. Затем, когда запускаю приложение через отладку, он требует переустановки, так как сигнатуры различаются, но я ничего не менял в коде, значит, скорее всего виноват ключ (keystore), с помощью которого я делаю экспорт приложения. Можно ли как-нибудь заюзать этот же ключ при отладке? Заранее благодарю. (OS X & Eclipse)

P.S. до этого работал под виндой, такой проблемы не наблюдалось, даже специально перепрошил ось на телефоне, мало-ли.

Comment: Вы используете свой ключ или пользуетесь debug.keystore? Если вы отлаживаете приложение, то я бы рекомендовал использовать debug.keystore, а уже при релизе подписывать своим ключом.

Comment: Я пользуюсь своим. То есть, мне просто нужно создать ключ с именем debug.keystore и везде его использовать? И еще вот такой вопрос: когда я сменил ключ на другой, приложение вообще перестало устанавливаться, это можно как-нибудь справить?

Answer (score 1):

1. По идее ключ debug.keystore установлен по умолчанию во многих IDE (просто нужно выбрать его в настройках). Не знаю, как у вас, а у меня в AIDE такое есть.
2. Если приложение не устанавливается, то сначала удалите старую версию, подписанную другим ключом. При установке приложения Android сравнивает подписи всех файлов в apk, и если хоть одна подпись не будет одинаковой, то установка невозможна. Помогает только удаление и последующая установка apk с изменённой подписью.

Comment: 1. Да, под виндоус с этим было всё хорошо, приложение ставилось отлично, а тут на тебе...
2. Я удалял. Я даже залезал под рутом в системные папки и удалял там. Не помогает (не могу гарантировать, что проблема не только у меня).

Но всё равно спасибо за наводку!

Comment: Насчёт второго пункта: какую ошибку выдаёт при установке?

Comment: "Пакет с таким названием уже установлен и имеет конфликтующую подпись". (Кстати, сейчас вот попробовал по-новой переустановить, такой ошибки уже не возникло, правда, пришлось его все-таки удалять). И вот что странно: при дебаге не работают кнопки меню и опций, это действительно меня пугает.

То ли дело в макоси, то ли в недоработанной прошивке телефона.

Comment: Уточните прошивку телефона, пожалуйста

Comment: http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=491974
Но сейчас стоит одна из самых первых ее версий.

И еще кое-что: в данный момент я отлаживаю через wi-fi, до этого было USB.

Comment: Что-ж...по идее дебаг по wifi - это уже плохая задумка. А в некоторых версия CyanoGen Mod могут быть некоторые инструменты дебаггинга. Учтите это. Сам столкнулся с этим на CyanoGen 9.

Comment: Спасибо, я учту. 
Сейчас нагуглил свою проблему, никто даже не знает, баг это или фичв :D

Answer (score 1):

При запуске приложения в Eclipse IDE в режиме отладки оно автоматически самим Eclipse подписывается файлом debug.keystore. Лежит этот файл в домашней папке пользователя. В OS X этот файл лежит по адресу ~/.android/debug.keystore . Учтите, что папка android в начале названия имеет точку, поэтому она скрыта. Возьмите и подпишите именно этим debug.keystore .